# Exception in thread "main" net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Page index out of range: 0 of -1

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am writing one Java program which takes the jrxml file and compile the jrxml and then export the report to image in png format.
After that I am trying to print that image through zebra printer connected to my desktop. But it throws a `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException` exception during execution. I don't know what this error means.

Error log

```
Exception in thread "main" net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Page index out of range: 0 of -1.
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRAbstractExporter.getPageRange(JRAbstractExporter.java:804)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRGraphics2DExporter.exportReportToGraphics2D(JRGraphics2DExporter.java:302)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRGraphics2DExporter.exportReport(JRGraphics2DExporter.java:229)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.print.JRPrinterAWT.printPageToImage(JRPrinterAWT.java:288)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrintManager.printToImage(JasperPrintManager.java:290)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrintManager.printPageToImage(JasperPrintManager.java:446)
at com.greycode.optimization.Materialsin.generateReport(Materialsin.java:62)
```

Complete Java code:

```
public class Materialsin {
    public static final void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Materialsin report = new Materialsin();
        try {
            report.generateReport(null, null);
        } catch (JRException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ConnectionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ZebraPrinterLanguageUnknownException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static JasperReport jasperReport = null;
    public void generateReport(Map<String, Object> parameters, List<Label> labels)
            throws JRException, IOException, ConnectionException, ZebraPrinterLanguageUnknownException {
        JRBeanCollectionDataSource dataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(labels);
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, dataSource);
        if (jasperPrint != null) {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\optimization\\Labels.png");
            BufferedImage rendered_image = null;
            rendered_image = (BufferedImage) JasperPrintManager.printPageToImage(jasperPrint, 0, 1.6f);
            ImageIO.write(rendered_image, "png", fos);

            try {
                Connection thePrinterConn = new DriverPrinterConnection("GC420t",1000,1000);
                thePrinterConn.open();

                ZebraPrinter zPrinter = ZebraPrinterFactory.getInstance(thePrinterConn);
                PrinterStatus printerStatus = zPrinter.getCurrentStatus();
                if(printerStatus.isReadyToPrint) {
                    ZebraImageI image = ZebraImageFactory
                        .getImage("C:\\Users\\optimization\\Labels.png");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Something went wrong");
                }
            } finally {
            }
        }
    }

    static {
        try {
            jasperReport = JasperCompileManager
                    .compileReport(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\optimization\\Label.jrxml"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JRException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: I haven't used Jasper reports, but it looks like you create an empty report (`report = new Materialsin();`) and then try and generate it. So it seems reasonable that it could not find page zero and have an unknown total number of pages (-1). Perhaps you need to add some content to your report first?

Comment: I have already added few static texts to jrxml for printing and as a test

Comment: OK. Perhaps the problem is `JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, ...)` which is called with `jasperReport` equal to `null`. Can you step through your code as it executes in your debugger?

Comment: Once jasperReport compiles it generate the new file .jasper to fill the report. So the value of jasperReport will be the location of jasperReport.

Comment: Sorry the location of .jasper